# What is a CTE scan, and what are its implications for performance?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to diagnose a slow query, using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. I'm new to the command so I've read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/using-explain.html . The query plan uses a "CTE scan", but I don't know what that is, compared to, say, a sequential scan - and more importantly, what a CTE scan means in general for query performance.

Comment: This is an advanced topic and I can't think of a layman explanation. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/CTEReadme - just trust the optmizer, it definitly is not as bad as a seqscan (how bad it is probably depends on the data cardinality).

Comment: Show your query and/or explain results.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

A "CTE scan" is a sequential scan of the materialized results of a CTE term (a named section like "blah" in a CTE like `WITH blah AS (SELECT ...)`.

*Materialized* means that PostgreSQL has calculated the results and turned them into a temporary store of rows, it isn't just using the CTE like a view.

The main implication is that selecting a small subset from a CTE term and discarding the rest can do a lot of wasted work, because the parts you discard must still be fully calculated.

### Postgres 11 and older

For details see [a recent blog post I wrote on the topic](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/).

### Postgres 12 +

PostgreSQL 12 and above can optimize through CTEs now, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html . Use the `MATERIALIZED` option to force the behaviour of PostgreSQL 11 or older.

Comment: PostgreSQL 12 features automatic, overrideable inlining using `WITH x as [NOT] MATERIALIZED`, potentially boosting performance of such queries ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html)).

Comment: @craigringer Thank you so much. That article was exactly what I needed to understand the problem. You save me so much time!